# PHP echo not displaying table tag

Tags: php, html-table, echo

I am trying to display the content of a database in a table and my table comes out as the tags. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

This is my code:

```
 echo $content .= "<tr>
                <th>$route = $total_submit</th>
                </tr>";

    $content .= " <tr>

          <td>" .'DELIVRD'. "</td>
                <td>" . $total_deliv . "</td>
                </tr>";
     $content .= " <tr>
                <td>" .'UNDELIV'. "</td>
                <td>" . $total_undeliv . "</td>
                </tr>";
                $content .= " <tr>
                <td>" .'ACK'. "</td>
              <td>" . $total_ack . "</td>
                </tr>";
               $content .= " <tr>
               <td>" .'EXPIRED'. "</td>
                <td>" . $total_expired . "</td>
                </tr>";
             $content .= " <tr>
                <td>" .'REJECTD'. "</td>
                <td>" . $total_rejected . "</td>
                </tr>";
                 }
          $constt .= "<table border='1px'>
                 <tr>
                <th>ROUTE PERFORMANCE</th>
                </tr>";
 echo $constt .=$content."</table>" ;
```

Comment: Where is open table tag?